# Integrating security testing to CI pipeline

Tags: security, web, continuous-integration

Is there anyway that we can run a static analysis on each commit to identify security issues in a web application ?

Web application is built using .Net framework 4.0 
Jenkins is used for CI
I have already gone through Owasp Zap tool. there are two options that i could find,
 1. Writing a selenium script to automate the login for the application and setting up the OWASP Zap in the build server.
 2. Configuring OWASP Zap tools authorization mechanism to login to web application.

I quite like to go with the 2nd approach.

Answer (score 1):

For any decent security static analyzer (Fortify, AppScan, CheckMarx, etc...), static analysis is not a quick activity, so you more likely would run it once a week or fortnight.  However, makers of such static analyzers target the bigger companies, and it is unusual for a smaller company would license them.

Simpler static analyzers such as findbugs and FxCop (or whatever they call it nowadays) can be run more often.  A few times, I've seen findbugs ran in CI during every build.

For web applications, another option is a dynamic analyzer such as OWASP ZAP, which is targeting automated scans in a CI pipeline.  This tool is free and there are good blogs and youtube videos about putting it in a CI pipeline.

Another great tool is Contrast Security, which is not static analysis but "IAST".  This tool runs during your testing phase and catches dangerous function calls as they are happening.  I believe the tool is mainly working for Java, .Net, and front end code.  Not sure how suitable it is for smaller companies.

Tell us more about your CI pipeline, the language and frameworks you are using, and the tools you are interested in and you may get a better answer.